# "e" vs. "ed" seguito da vocale diversa da "e"

Tags: grammar, conjunctions, prepositions

Alle elementari mi insegnarono a trasformare "e" in "ed" se era seguita da una qualunque vocale, mentre qualche anno fa a un corso di sceneggiatura l'insegnante disse che ultimamente *si preferiva* trasformarla in "ed" solamente quando era seguita da "e" (e non dalle altre vocali).

Non ricordo se si stesse riferendo solo a qualche editor in particolare (Disney? Bonelli?) o se stesse parlando in generale.

Da qui il dubbio: alcune case editrici preferiscono un modo piuttosto che un altro? quanto sono diffuse (più o meno) le due varianti?

Si noti che non ricordo se disse che la stessa cosa valeva anche per "a" vs. "ad", ma suppongo che una volta scelto se mettere o meno la "d" convenga essere coerenti.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Il tuo insegnante aveva ragione. [Accademia della Crusca](http://www.accademiadellacrusca.it/it/lingua-italiana/consulenza-linguistica/domande-risposte/d-eufonica), come al solito:

> L'uso della 'd' eufonica, secondo le indicazioni del famoso storico della lingua Bruno Migliorini, dovrebbe essere limitato ai casi di incontro della stessa vocale, quindi nei casi in cui la congiunzione *e* e la preposizione *a* precedano parole inizianti rispettivamente per *e* e per *a* (es. *ed ecco, ad andare, ad ascoltare*, ecc.).

[Attenzione](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/d-eufonica-prontuario_%28Enciclopedia-dell%27Italiano%29/) ai seguenti casi:

- sequenze come *ed editori, ad Adamo, ad adattare* e simili (quando la vocale successiva è seguita a sua volta dalla *d*) vanno evitate;
- ci sono locuzioni fisse dove l'uso della d eufonica è praticamente cristallizzato anche fra vocali di diverso timbro: *ad eccezione di, ad esempio, ad ogni buon conto, ad essi*.

[Manuale di redazione](http://books.google.se/books?id=S-x-hxAL7PQC) di Mariuccia Teroni (2007, Apogeo Editore, pagina 133) spiega gli altri dettagli.

Comment: Congratulazioni, ottima risposta; +1.

Comment: Giusto ma... secondo me qualche volta si usa la _d_ eufonica anche per influenzare la sillabazione e quindi il ritmo della frase. Questo vale sicuramente in letteratura, ma oserei dire che capita anche di farlo istintivamente nel linguaggio parlato. Ho disarmato il mio aggressore e puntandogli la pistola gli dico ghignando: "Ed ora?". Proprio in una sceneggiatura non metterei mai "E ora?", mi si impasta la lingua.
(Comunque alla fine decide il correttore di bozze secondo le norme redazionali. :-) )

Comment: @Mauro Come ho già detto, ci sono frase fatte in qui *ed* si usa spesso. *Qui ed ora* può essere un bel esempio a pari con le altre locuzione latine come *ad esempio* ecc. :) Comunque, non è per niente strano di sentire [E ora dove andiamo?](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_ora_dove_andiamo%3F) oppure [E ora qualcosa di complatamente diverso](http://it.wikipedia.org/wiki/E_ora_qualcosa_di_completamente_diverso), non trovi?