# The use of "a" versus "ad" or "e" versus "ed"

Tags: prepositions

I would like to know how compatible are  *e* and *ed*, or *a* and *ad*. My understanding is that the *d* is added when the following word starts with a vowel, but since this also makes things sound somewhat more formal, such construct is not always employed in the construction of sentences in standard Italian. Is this observation correct, or am I missing something?

Comment: ***La famosa questione della d eufonica,*** cioè di quella d che viene aggiunta alla preposizione a trasformandola in ad e alla congiunzione e trasformandola in ed quando sono seguite da parola che comincia per vocale. Lo scopo è di rendere il suono più gradevole. http://dizionari.corriere.it/dizionario-si-dice/A/a-ad.shtml

Comment: Related question (duplicate?): http://italian.stackexchange.com/q/1270