# Cambia la preposizione in base al verbo?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Cambia la preposizione a seconda del verbo? 
Ho molti dubbi e non so se siano fondati o meno. 
In questo specifico caso parlo di complementi di luogo. 
Per esempio:

1) Vado/sono alla/a una festa, la festa a cui sono andato.
È successo in una festa, la festa in cui è successo.

2) Sono/vado a un corso di inglese, il corso a cui sono andato.
Insegno in un corso d'inglese, il corso in cui insegno.

3) Vado/sono a una gara/un torneo, il torneo a cui sono andato.
Ho gareggiato in un torneo, il torneo in cui ho gareggiato.

4) Sono andato/sono andato a un appuntamento/incontro, l'appuntamento/incontro a cui sono andato.
Il fatto è avvenuto in appuntamento/incontro, l'appuntamento/incontro in cui è avvenuto il fatto.

5) Siamo andati a una partita, la partita a cui siamo andati.
È successo in quella partita, la partita in cui è successo.

Scusate per le troppe frasi, però mi servirebbero dei chiarimenti per capire meglio.

Comment: Ogni tanto torni qui e poni domande su come esprimere i complementi di luogo e sulle preposizioni “a” e “in”. Mi rendo conto che per uno straniero siano problematici, ma a parte quello che ti possono dire i dizionari e le [grammatiche](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/preposizioni_(Enciclopedia-dell'Italiano)/), non rimane molto altro che leggere testi italiani e conversare in italiano. Anche gli italiani hanno dubbi e vanno a orecchio, e spesso più di una risposta è “corretta” o almeno accettabile dalla maggioranza degli italiani.

Comment: Me ne rendo conto. Potrebbe comunque chiarirmi questi dubbi?

Comment: Se vuoi seguire questo metodo per imparare le preposizioni, non possiamo che rispondere alle tue domande. Resta valido, però, quello che ti abbiamo detto più volte a proposito di questo argomento, il più complesso dell’italIano, forse, perché si basa essenzialmente sull’uso.

Comment: 1) Vanno bene; 2) Vanno bene, ma forse per l’influenza dei dialetti centrali il secondo esempio “mi suona” meglio con la prep. “a” (entrambe comunque sono accettabili); 2) e 3) vanno bene; 4) il primo esempio va bene, nel secondo è meglio usare “durante”, in ogni caso è necessario l’articolo; 5) vanno bene.

Comment: Avrei una domanda: è successo in quella partita è un complemento di luogo(Stato in luogo)?  Lo chiedo perché lei mi suggeriva l'utilizzo di "durante" per la seconda frase dell'esempio numero 5. Se volessi parlare di un appuntamento/incontro/partita come complemento di stato in luogo quale preposizione dovrei usare? Perché si usa "a" se parliamo di una destinazione (la partita/appuntamento a cui vado)

Comment: @Nakamura: suggerivo l’uso di “durante” nell’esempio 4. «Il fatto è avvenuto durante l’incontro / un incontro». Effettivamente, possiamo utilizzarlo anche nell’esempio 5. «È successo durante quella partita». Perché però non “suona” strano usare “in”? Per l’uso. Anche in questo caso dobbiamo fare riferimento alla maggiore o minore frequenza di un termine. Il calcio, come si sa, è uno sport di cui si parla tanto, in Italia.

Comment: @Nakamura: Quanto alla definizione dei complementi, in questi casi si tratta di un complemento di tempo, non di luogo. Quando è successo? Durante la partita.

Comment: @Nakamura: riguardo alla definizione dei complementi e all’uso delle preposizioni. In italiano, più preposizioni sono usate per esprimere lo stesso complemento, soprattutto di luogo. Non sempre la “destinazione” (vale a dire il complemento di moto a luogo) si esprime con “a”. Vado in pizzeria, al cinema, a teatro, in campagna, dal dottore, all’ospedale, da Marco, in Cina, a Londra, ecc. Medesimo discorso vale per lo stato in luogo: Sto a casa, in Italia, a New York, da Luca. La preposizione è legata al nome che indica il luogo, non al verbo, come più volte abbiamo provato a specificare.

Comment: Capisco. Dunque l'utilizzo di "in"  nella seconda frase dell'esempio numeto 4 e 5 indica un complemento di tempo più che di luogo, così come durante? Era questa la domanda che le avevo rivolto.

Comment: @Nakamura: esatto. In quei particolari esempi "in" introduce un complemento di tempo.

Comment: Mentre per quanto riguarda i secondi esempi del numero 1, 2 e 3 parliamo di effettivi complementi di luogo, giusto?

Answer (score 3):

Il verbo *andare* regge in genere un complemento di *moto a luogo* che di solito vuole la preposizione *a*.

Non succede sempre: un esempio è *andare per campi* (moto attraverso luogo).

Perciò *andare a una festa*, *andare a un corso di inglese*, *andare a una partita*, *andare a teatro*. Ma, se commetti un reato, *vai in prigione*. Oppure  *vai in Sicilia* ad ammirare i templi greci o *vai a Cipro* per una vacanza. Si va *in paradiso* o *all'inferno*.

C'è una regola unica? Purtroppo no, come si capisce dagli ultimi casi. Con i nomi di luogo è sempre complicato (vedi [Usage of prepositions "a" and "in" in statements about places and directions](https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1192/)). Si può capire *in prigione* perché è un luogo dove si sta a lungo, la differenza tra paradiso e inferno è più complicata da giustificare.

Un complemento di *stato in luogo* vuole normalmente *in*. Anche qui però ci sono “eccezioni”: *sono a cena, ti prego di chiamare più tardi*, *ho incontrato Luca a lezione*.

L'unico modo per cavarsela è conoscere l'uso. Non sempre ce la caviamo, nel senso che capita di dire o sentire la proposizione sbagliata.

Answer (score 0):

Può essere utile ricordare la regola latina della "città o piccola isola" che comportava il caso locativo (di fatto uguale al genitivo).
Questo è rimasto inconsciamente in italiano per cui

vado/sono *IN* Spagna, Germania, Scozia, Sardegna, Liguria, Groenlandia, Madagascar..
ma
vado/sono *A* Madrid, Berlino, Inverness, Cagliari, Genova, Lampedusa, Cipro...

Ovviamente il concetto di "piccola isola" è questionabile e su questo conviene rifarsi all'uso corrente.

P.S. "sono a Inverness" diviene eufonicamente "sono ad Inverness"

Comment: Benvenuto su Italian.SE!

Comment: Per la "d" eufonica vedi [questa risposta](https://italian.stackexchange.com/a/1271/707).