# Is this correct?

Tags: grammar, translation, sentences

I want to say "I spent the whole day yesterday learning Italian"

> ieri sto passai tutto il giorno imparare l'italiano

This is my first attempt in forming a complete sentence, probably fill with silly mistakes. Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to ItalianSE!!!

Answer (score 5):

The correct sentence would be:

> Ieri ho passato tutto il giorno a imparare l’italiano.

using the *passato prossimo* verbal form.

As correctly reported by @egreg, in some varieties of Italian (Sicilian, for instance) the *passato remoto* would be used, because ieri is a completed span of time.

So the sentence in this case would be:

> Ieri passai tutto il giorno a imparare l’italiano.

Comment: You can also simply say "a imparare" (see https://italian.stackexchange.com/questions/1270/e-vs-ed-seguito-da-vocale-diversa-da-e), which maybe is easier for a beginner.

Comment: Yes, “a imparare” is better than “ad imparare”: that “d” is generally only used when there are two equal vowels one after another (“ad andare”).

Comment: @DaG. You're right. Answer modified.

Comment: In some varieties of Italian (Sicilian, for instance) the *passato remoto* would be used, because *ieri* is a completed span of time.